# Slow boot time since upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10

Tags: 12.04, boot

I have tried for quite a while now to reduce my boot time, disabled some startup items, removed packages that were causing crashes after boot, removed ureadahead pack files, reinstalled ureadahead, uninstalled ureadahead and installed e4rat....and nothing has made that much difference.
e4rat made the biggest difference with a reduction of a few seconds but my boot time is still around 80 seconds.

Can anyone help?

Dmesg and bootchart below:

```
[    2.156198] usb 1-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    2.248892] hub 1-2.3:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.249051] hub 1-2.3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.336222] usb 1-2.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[    2.506968] [drm] initialized overlay support
[    2.556224] usb 1-2.3.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[    2.703484] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.703601] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50
[    2.703677] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.703681] drm: registered panic notifier
[    2.703712] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.606304] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:(null)
[   28.036880] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   28.049443] init: bootchart pre-stop process (483) terminated with status 1
[   28.050216] init: bootchart main process (475) killed by TERM signal
[   28.065200] udevd[488]: starting version 175
[   28.133129] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   28.226043] Adding 1250300k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1250300k 
[   28.281691] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[   28.282808] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   28.309624] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
[   28.315511] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   28.315516] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   28.315592] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   28.315608] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   28.418819] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[   28.418824] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[   28.419084] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   28.422059] Registered led device: phy0-led
[   28.422103] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   28.446514] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   28.464570] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   28.471575] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: CardBus bridge found [1028:01c2]
[   28.471602] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: O2: enabling read prefetch/write burst. If you experience problems or performance issues, use the yenta_socket parameter 'o2_speedup=off'
[   28.496643] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   28.496710] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   28.496746] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   28.573257] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input5
[   28.573373] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input6
[   28.597084] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: ISA IRQ mask 0x0cb8, PCI irq 18
[   28.597091] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: Socket status: 30000006
[   28.597096] pci_bus 0000:03: Raising subordinate bus# of parent bus (#03) from #04 to #07
[   28.597379] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[   28.597384] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0x2000-0x2fff: excluding 0x2000-0x20ff
[   28.602146] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=674 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.602161] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.602728] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=674 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.602758] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.603064] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=674 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.603099] type=1400 audit(1336601911.623:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   28.608611]  0x2400-0x24ff
[   28.613044] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff]
[   28.613050] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff: excluding 0xe0000000-0xe03fffff
[   28.613066] yenta_cardbus 0000:03:01.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe4000000-0xe7ffffff pref]
[   28.613070] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe4000000-0xe7ffffff: excluding 0xe4000000-0xe7ffffff
[   28.641184] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input7
[   28.671195] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   28.671202] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   28.671204] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   28.671208] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   28.671212] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   28.671216] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   28.671219] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   28.671223] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   28.722883] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   28.722907] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   28.722910] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   28.722914] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   28.722916] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   28.722923] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   28.723278] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[   28.745314] init: bootchart post-stop process (484) terminated with status 2
[   28.745922] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   28.836341] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0x100-0x3af: excluding 0x170-0x177 0x1f0-0x1f7 0x370-0x377
[   28.838578] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0x3e0-0x4ff: excluding 0x3f0-0x3ff 0x4d0-0x4d7
[   28.839342] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0x820-0x8ff: clean.
[   28.840025] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0xc00-0xcf7: excluding 0xc80-0xcbf
[   28.840587] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x0c0000-0x0fffff: excluding 0xc0000-0xcffff 0xe0000-0xfffff
[   28.840628] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff: excluding 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff
[   28.840666] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x60000000-0x60ffffff: excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
[   28.840704] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: IO port probe 0xa00-0xaff: clean.
[   29.364319] input: DualPoint Stick as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input8
[   29.384676] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input9
[   29.431991] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr
[   29.692514] init: failsafe main process (920) killed by TERM signal
[   29.793891] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.793895] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.812100] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.812107] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.812110] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   29.817985] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   29.846554] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   29.846927] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ef1a9e00 submission failed
[   29.864228] type=1400 audit(1336601912.887:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=1030 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.869792] type=1400 audit(1336601912.891:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1028 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.872809] type=1400 audit(1336601912.895:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1028 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.876653] type=1400 audit(1336601912.899:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1031 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.058346] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
[   30.155088] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   30.155428] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   30.158293] tg3 0000:09:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   30.196049] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   30.197106] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   30.296754] init: gdm main process (1171) killed by TERM signal
```

[bootchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhsrq.png)

It seems to be getting worse over time, maybe with each successive boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which in my case seems to have been something to do with Ubuntu waiting for a IPv6 response from the router, which was disabled on the router.

After I enabled it, the boot proceeded smoothly with only a 0.8 second delay rather than 20 seconds. May not be the same problem but it's only a few seconds to test and probably worth a go.